# Character Handling VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, try-catch

If I wanted to use a Try-Catch for a char and to make sure that it wouldn't have the program run when I typed in a numeric value how would I do that in visual basic? Example of a small snippet of code would be great.

Comment: @Mitch I am just learning Visual Basic and I am trying to handle an exception from a character type. Could you at least be a little more specific? Not sure why I needed a down vote for asking a question. : /

Comment: @Mark By Making a masked text box or something you mean? Im still pretty new to visual basic.

Comment: Btw,: it's not my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a  `Try/Catch` for normal program control flow. Exceptions are for just that: exceptional circumstances you do not expect to occur normally.

Rather than use an exception to blow up when a character contains a numeric, prevent it being stored 
in the first instance.

A good way to achieve this is by adding a [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventhandler.aspx) handler.

Here's an example of a KeyPress handler that allows only Numerics and backspace (it's in C# but it is easy to convert to VB.NET):

```
    private void txtTimeout_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b');
    }
```

> Set KeyPressEventArgs.Handled to true to cancel the KeyPress event.
>   This keeps the control from processing the key press.

There are further examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventhandler.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and on StackOverflow.

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) _
    Handles textBox1.KeyPress

    ' Determine what is a valid key press 
    If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = True Then 
        ' Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is numeric
        e.Handled = True 
    End If 

End Sub
```